# How to replace all characters with condition [Python]

Tags: python, string, replace, char

Here is my code to replace a camelCase input with snake_case:

```
camel_case = str(input(" "))
snake_case = ""
# check each characters in string
for char in camel_case:
    if char.isupper(): # checking if it is upper or not
        snake_case = camel_case.replace(char, "_"+char.lower())
print(snake_case)
```

And with the input `userName` , it outputs `user_name`. But with the input with more than two Capital characters, for example, `goodUserName` only outputs `goodUser_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the string in place. Instead, just create a new string:

```
output = ""
for char in camel_case:
    if char.isupper():
        output += "_"
    output += char.lower()
```

Or, in one line:

```
"".join("_"+char.lower() if char.isupper() else char.lower() for char in camel_case)
```